# cycle2 fails with images inside php script

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-cycle2

I can't get the cycle2 pager to work and I've checked the various questions and answers on this topic.  I'm beginning to think it may have to do with my setup:  the user clicks one of several buttons and that brings up one or more thumbnail images from a mysql database.  Each thumbnail is related via the database to one or more larger images that I'd like to play in a slideshow.  An ajax call sends the info about which thumb was clicked and a server page retrieves the larger images from a directory and displays them all in a div on the calling page as follows:

```
    <?php

    $thumb_path = $_POST['thumb_path'];

    ob_start();
    echo basename($thumb_path, ".png");
    $thumb_name = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $dir = "pathTo/$thumb_name/*.png";

    $images = glob( $dir );

    foreach( $images as $image ):
        echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
    endforeach;

    ?>
```

So far, so good as all the larger images are displayed (statically, all at once) in the div.  The problem comes when I try to wrap the php script above in any of the cycle2 pagers (I'd like to use the one that automatically creates thumbnails for navigating the larger images, but none work).  What happens is that all the larger images are loaded on top of each other without any navigation controls (thumbnails, dots, numbers etc. as the case may be).  The larger images do play if I set the

```
    data-cycle-timeout
```

parameter to something other than zero, but I'd like to set it to zero and let the users navigate the larger images themselves.

I'm a total noob at web programming and it's taken a while to get this stuff to work, chiefly by studying code snippets I've found on the web.  I hope any solution doesn't involve a major redesign.

Thanks in advance for any help.